# Rowwise division with batch data

Tags: tensorflow

Given a tensor `A` of shape `[?, n, l]` and a tensor `D` of shape `[?, n]`, I want to divide each row of tensor `a` of shape `[n,l]` of `A` by the corresponding scalar of `D`.

I thought I could somehow do this by using the broadcasting behavior of `tf.div`. Unfortunatley I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to extend `D` to match the dimension of `A`:

```
res = A / D[...,tf.newaxis])
```

Comment: So `A/tf.expand_dim(D, axis=2) ` would have the same effect?